# Under what conditions can malware bypass macOS Catalina's permission system?

Tags: malware, macos, permissions, spyware

Catalina has some new security features which include System Preferences > Security & Privacy features, which requires apps to request access to specific computer functionality such as camera, microphone, full disk access, input monitoring, etc.

Under what conditions could malware bypass such requirements to use those components without permission, and would it still be visible inside System Preferences > Security & Privacy or would they be capable of hiding their presence?

Comment: This question would require an answer the size of a book. Even a short overview would have to contain a lot of sources and still be very long to be somewhat complete in answering the questions you ask in this question. Could you edit your question to contain one, more precise question? (Note that, even when a question is on hold or closed, you can edit your question. If it is a good question after editing, it will be reopened.)

Comment: Since you do a lot of stuff in your browser, it's enough for malware to be able to modify the executable of Chrome, Firefox, etc.. and that is OS Version Independent.

Comment: @MechMK1 in which case the malware would only be executed during browser runtime?

Comment: @Luc I've edited my question to one more precise, rather than multiple.

Comment: @user225844 Thanks! I did another pass and fixed the title and some wording. Is this what you mean? I think the question is now okay to reopen and will vote to do so. Please edit it again if I misunderstood and mis-edited your question.

Comment: @user225844 Malware can - in general - run at any time and do anything.

Comment: @MechMK1 I don't know macOS, but it seems similar to Android's model, and on Android, malware definitely can't do what you claim without getting the necessary permissions from the user. It would require a vulnerability in the OS (which would probably be patched soon in an up-to-date system) to get camera access without tricking the user into clicking "allow". As an answer or even a hint, that remark needs to be substantiated by quite a bit.

Comment: @Luc I know that saying "it can do anything" is not perfectly accurate, but it's difficult to explain the nuances of a complicated permission system in one comment.

Comment: https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/04/actively-exploited-mac-0-day-neutered-core-os-security-defenses/?comments=1 might have the answers you're looking for.